# Regular Expressions Vbscript

Tags: regex, asp-classic, vbscript

I am fiddling with regular expressions to shorten a string splitting routine I have been using.

I have a string for my cart that is submitted to an asp script as follows:

```
addnothing|-1, addRST115400112*2xl|0, addnothing|-1, addnothing|-1, addRST115400115*xs|0, addnothing|-1
```

I want to be able to extract the two entries that represent two stock items:

```
addRST115400112*2xl|0
addRST115400115*xs|0
```

I have managed to get this bit of code to work but I am unsure about the pattern I am using:

```
add[^n](.*)\*(.*)\|[0-9],
```

This returns this:

```
addRST115400112*2xl|0, addnothing|-1, addnothing|-1, addRST115400115*xs|0,
```

but I only want it to return :

```
addRST115400112*2xl|0
addRST115400115*xs|0
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1):

You were matching it **greedily** (`.*` eats as much as it can so in your case it ends up eating till the last `\|[0-9]` i.e `|0`)

You should match it **lazily** by using `.*?` instead of `.*`

---

So your regex should be

```
add(?!nothing)(.*?)\*(.*?)\|\d
```

`\d` is similar to `[0-9]`

`(?!nothing)` is just a check..it doesn't match or consume anything..it's better then `[^n]` cuz it's more reliable,expressive and doesnt eat anything

Comment: There is a follow up to my question which is I will also be passing in a remRST115400112*2xl|0 to remove the item from the basket and I don;t want to have to use different functions to search for what I want to achieve.

Comment: @GrahamCole you can use `(add|rem)(?!nothing)(.*?)\*(.*?)\|\d`..if i got u right

Comment: I just wanted to follow up on this if you don't mind.  The last part of the regex pattern \|\d is actually optional because the site currently does not pass this in.  How can I make this bit optional in the pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to keep the .Pattern simple (this is VBScript!) and to make tinkering with it easier (what really singles out stock items is by no means clear):

```
  Dim sInp  : sInp      = "addnothing|-1, addRST115400112*2xl|0, addnothing|-1, addnothing|-1, addRST115400115*xs|0, addnothing|-1"
  Dim reCut : Set reCut = New RegExp
  reCut.Global  = True
  reCut.Pattern = "addR[^|]+\|\d"
  Dim oMTS : Set oMTS = reCut.Execute(sInp)
  If 2 = oMTS.Count Then
     WScript.Echo "Success:", Join(Array(oMTS(0).Value, oMTS(1).Value))
  Else
     WScript.Echo "Bingo:", reCut.Pattern
  End If
```

output:

```
Success: addRST115400112*2xl|0 addRST115400115*xs|0
```

Comment: I see your point however stock codes do not follow a specific pattern and certainly do not always start with an R.  There is a followup to my question which is I will also be passing in a remRST115400112*2xl|0 to remove the item.